# Using cron job to run PHP export_wp script to export XML of posts

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, cron

I want to run a cron job to run a PHP script that exports an XML of "posts" but I am failing to make it happen. Here is where I'm at:

```
<?php
function haven_export_posts() {
$args=array(
    'content' => 'posts',
    'status' => 'published');

ob_start();
export_wp($args);
$xml = ob_get_clean();

file_put_contents( ABSPATH . 'path to directory/haven_export_posts.xml', $xml);
}
?>
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Is your function not working itself or your problem is to trigger that function with a cron job? What are you using to trigger that function? Please could you be more explicit updating your question?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec the function itself isn't working. I haven't setup the cron job yet. This is a bit out of my comfort zone dabbling in functions and building scripts like this, so maybe I'm missing something obvious.. like triggering the function. How do I go about doing that? I figured I could just put this on a php page and then by loading that page it would trigger it. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Did you succeed? Cause I'm trying to do the same